# iPhone apps not showing in App Store on iPad with iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, app-store-connect

## Resolved

There was a problem on Apple's side of the App Store, which resolved itself after a few weeks.

## Original post

For about a week now, my company's apps we've developed for iPhone are not visible anymore in the App Store app on iPad models. They were visible before. iPad-targeted apps are still visible on iPads.

When searching Google for the apps on a computer, they can be found, downloaded with iTunes and installed on an iPad.

When searching Google on an iPad with Safari, the apps can also be found, downloaded and installed on an iPad.

On an iPhone 4 (iOS 6.0) and iPod Touch (iOS 5.1.1) they are visible in the App Store app on the device.

In iTunesConnect, the apps are set to be available in our geographic region. The apps are build against versions 4.3, 5.0 or 6.0 of the SDK, but they all should be compatible to 6.0.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction of where to look to get these apps visible in the App Store app on iPads again.

Thanks beforehand

Edit 1: Both the "iPad" and "iPhone" search results turn up empty.
Edit 2: Added link to app having problems.
Edit 3: Removed Edit 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** as of 12-18, our apps are now appearing on the iPad iOS6 App Store.

I have the same issue.  I sent Apple multiple support requests and received the following response.  They claim they are "aware of this issue", "working to resolve", and "may take six to eight weeks" (!?!) to fix.

> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Support. My name is Jasmine,
>   and I will be happy to assist you today.
>
> I understand that when you search for your app, Doximity, on the iPad
>   with iOS 6, that you receive a message, "No Results Found". Is this
>   correct?
>
> I am sorry for the inconvenience and frustration this may be causing
>   you.
>
> Thank you for your information. Apple is aware of this issue and is
>   currently working to resolve it. It may take six to eight weeks for
>   the issue to remedied. Again, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Let us hope Apple has been aware of the problem since it first happened. Then we would only have to wait two to four more weeks!

Comment: hi,, I faced the same issue since last week. If apple fixed this, why Im still getting this. I developed an iPhone app. now my client complaining when he search it from the iPad it is not displaying. Why is that? plz anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE - Jan 7, 2013 - Our app Rogerthat is now visible in the App Store on IPad**

I am having exactly the same problem. Also started about one week ago (around Oct 22, 2012). We are also based in Belgium.

Our app id: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rogerthat/id446796149

Comment: We have received reports of people, who are still running iOS5 on their iPads, who can see the apps of our company in the App Store app. We currently do not have any iPads running iOS5 to troubleshoot this problem further. Maybe it's something worth looking into.

Comment: Indeed on iOS5 the app 'rogerthat' can be found in the appstore (on iPad3). On iOS6 iPad3 it cannot be found.

I am 100% sure that I could find the previous version of our app on iOS6 (2 weeks ago), but I had to click on "iPhone apps" in the app store.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Apple support. I'll update this SO thread when I have news.

Comment: According to the developer.apple.com forum. A number of developers are having this same problem, including myself for 2 different apps.

Comment: Indeed - some of the apple dev forum threads: https://devforums.apple.com/message/749920  https://devforums.apple.com/message/749934

Comment: Upgraded iPad3 to iOS 6.0.1: unfortunately this problem is NOT fixed

Comment: I have seen several reports of people stating the problem may be fixed in 6 to 8 weeks. The problem seems to be originating when the criteria you're searching for does not contain any search results for iPad only apps.

Answer (score 1):

when you are on the ipad in appstore, choose to show iphone apps ;-)

Comment: Afraid those search results are empty as well. (I'll update my OP) (Thanks for the quick response)

Comment: i tried to check but its not availble in german appstore. and it ask me to change the store. if you app has been just approved for appstore, give 24h before it will show up in search.

Comment: This version of the app has been approved for two days now, while the app has been in the stores for almost 2 monhts. I now have enabled the app to be available worldwide. (Don't know how long this will take for changes to be visible)

Comment: i can see it now on appstore. i just clicked the link.

Comment: But not if you search for it through the App Store app, I guess? :-) (This is the problem, actually)

Comment: the problem is that the app doesn't appear for either "iPad" or "iPhone" search results.